# How to sort a slice of version strings in Go

Tags: sorting, go

I have array full of versions of type `String` & need to sort, but current sort method is sorting it incorrectly

```
apiVersions := []string{"1.4", "1.12", "1.21", "1.8"}
```

On sorting `apiVersions`, the array looks like `["1.12", "1.21", "1.4", "1.8"]` instead of `["1.4", "1.8", "1.12", "1.21"]`

Comment: Why did you not split the strings at the `.` characters, convert each part to an integer and sort them numerically, instead of alphabetically?

Comment: The sorting algorithm does not know about the semantic meaning of your strings: the sorting algorithm does not know your strings hold versions and how to order them. The sorting algorithm just sorts your strings byte-wise. You have to define your `less()` function that tells how to order versions stored as strings, and use that with `sort.Slice()`.

Comment: If those are intended to be semantic versions, I would suggest just using an existing library to parse and compare them so you don't miss any additional version components is they are added later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use one of the standard Go semantic version compare packages to perform this, rather than re-inventing the wheel. For starters, use the [hashicorp/go-version](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-version) package to semantically compare two version strings

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"

    "github.com/hashicorp/go-version"
)

type byVersion []string

func (s byVersion) Len() int {
    return len(s)
}

func (s byVersion) Swap(i, j int) {
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
}

func (s byVersion) Less(i, j int) bool {
    v1, err := version.NewVersion(s[i])
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    v2, err := version.NewVersion(s[j])
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return v1.LessThan(v2)
}

func main() {
    versions := []string{"1.4", "1.12", "1.21", "1.8"}
    sort.Sort(byVersion(versions))
    fmt.Println(versions)
}
```

produces the desired result as expected.

```
[1.4 1.8 1.12 1.21]
```